# Only print footnote rules for certain streams when they're alone on the page

Tags: footnotes, rules, reledmac, reledpar

I'm using the reledmac package, along with the reledpar package, and I'd like to modify how the footnote rules appear. But, being a novice, I can only get so far. (See MWE).

The document contains four footnote streams: `footnoteA (1, 2, 3…) & footnoteB (a, b, c…)`, confined to the left-hand side; and `footnoteC (1, 2, 3…) & footnoteD (a, b, c…)`, confined to the right-hand side. However, I think that when footnotes belonging to both streams appear on the same page, the printing of footnote rules above *each* footnote stream is too much. Often this means seeing four horizontal foot rules when looking at two facing pages.

Of course, the `footnoteA & footnoteC` rules are always printed first on their respective pages, and it's easy to remove the footnote rules above the `footnoteB & footnoteD` streams—you just add the following lines to the preamble:

```
\let\footnoteruleB=\relax
\let\footnoteruleD=\relax
```

But once you do this, when the `footnoteB` stream (or the `footnoteD` stream on the right-hand page) is the only stream appearing at the bottom of its page, there is no footnote rule at all. (See MWE). And this is inconsistent with the rest of the document.

So here is the question: is it possible to configure the document to print the footnote rule above the `footnoteB` stream (and above the `footnoteD` stream on the right-hand page) *if and only if* the `footnoteB` stream (or the `footnoteD` stream) is the *only* stream appearing at the bottom of its page? In other words, is it possible to have the rule printed above the `footnoteB` (or `footnoteD`) stream when it is *alone* on the page, but to have it suppressed when it is preceded by the notes of the `footnoteA` (or `footnoteC`) stream?

Given LaTeX's power and configurability, it seems that this should be possible. Any help would be much appreciated. The MWE shows how far I've managed to get.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage[series={A,B,C,D},noend,noeledsec,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{latin}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteB}{\alph{footnoteB}}     
\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteD}{\alph{footnoteD}}     
\onlysideX[A]{L}        % Keeps the A note stream on the left-hand side. Etc.
\onlysideX[B]{L}
\onlysideX[C]{R}
\onlysideX[D]{R}
\let\footnoteruleB=\relax   % Removes the rule above footnoteB stream, but everywhere in doc.
\let\footnoteruleD=\relax

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\autopar

Lorem\footnoteA{Vivamus sem erat} ipsum dolor sit amet\footnoteB{Sed in tempus enim}, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam erat erat, tristique a sodales et, egestas vitae justo. Vivamus sem erat, vehicula sit amet tincidunt et, vulputate ut lectus. Nam maximus pretium lectus, in placerat massa interdum eu. Nulla nec tincidunt nunc, venenatis tempus elit. Maecenas hendrerit nunc nec congue tempus. Nullam hendrerit et arcu sed commodo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aliquam dapibus dolor in finibus porttitor. Suspendisse eu nisl magna. Aliquam lacinia porttitor ligula quis convallis. Nam placerat, sem tempor fringilla mollis, odio ligula ultricies ante, vel hendrerit arcu lacus quis ipsum. Sed in tempus enim, et hendrerit arcu. Aliquam rutrum suscipit magna, sit amet dictum lectus molestie non.

Donec non suscipit metus. Quisque varius, metus non tempus luctus, ante metus finibus justo, sit amet eleifend nisi augue nec neque. Cras placerat volutpat libero, eget dapibus lectus imperdiet et. Ut ut risus varius, imperdiet neque varius, maximus quam. Sed ullamcorper tortor eget semper venenatis. Nullam mattis accumsan egestas. Fusce eleifend ipsum sed quam feugiat, nec dapibus odio vestibulum. Etiam ultricies aliquet ligula. Proin tincidunt rhoncus mi ac facilisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et nisl nibh. Nullam et lorem tincidunt, ultrices augue et, ultrices libero. Nulla ut ante gravida odio iaculis luctus. Quisque a convallis erat. Vestibulum efficitur odio leo, sed ullamcorper dolor facilisis sit amet. Curabitur at tristique ligula, eleifend mollis nisl. In metus augue, dictum quis lobortis vitae, aliquam sed tellus. Praesent volutpat aliquet tincidunt. Cras vehicula, ante ut sollicitudin feugiat, ante urna varius est, lobortis dictum lectus nibh at lacus. Aliquam efficitur, dui id aliquet feugiat, purus tellus rhoncus purus, a consequat eros mi semper turpis. Ut mauris augue, suscipit a ante quis, bibendum laoreet justo. Suspendisse ac libero commodo, vestibulum nisi ut, dictum ipsum. Vivamus ac dolor quis urna sodales blandit. Morbi porta metus dolor, non aliquam turpis aliquam auctor. Vestibulum eleifend elit massa, eu convallis mi laoreet nec. Duis ut commodo nulla. Aenean varius pharetra ante ac sagittis. Sed tincidunt, erat at gravida feugiat, magna elit tempus neque, et varius nisi sem non mauris. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut pellentesque nulla metus, sed viverra risus sagittis eget. Fusce iaculis nisl eu elementum sollicitudin. Sed vulputate mattis mauris, non varius orci mollis a. Donec nec massa fringilla, luctus ante nec, auctor leo. Quisque fringilla tortor lacus, ut porttitor quam semper ac. Vivamus vel efficitur magna, a condimentum massa. Praesent convallis tempor rutrum. Phasellus ultricies fermentum nisl quis consectetur. Etiam congue ut magna a suscipit. Etiam id urna vel justo convallis interdum. Nullam efficitur sapien in nibh fringilla dapibus. Aenean at risus fringilla, dictum sapien id, tempus eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam erat erat, tristique a sodales et, egestas vitae justo. Vivamus sem erat, vehicula sit amet tincidunt et, vulputate ut lectus. Nam maximus pretium lectus, in placerat massa interdum eu. Nulla nec tincidunt nunc, venenatis tempus elit. Maecenas hendrerit nunc nec congue tempus. Nullam hendrerit et arcu sed commodo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aliquam dapibus dolor in finibus porttitor. Suspendisse eu nisl magna. Aliquam lacinia porttitor ligula quis convallis. Nam placerat, sem tempor fringilla mollis, odio ligula ultricies ante, vel hendrerit arcu lacus quis ipsum. Sed in tempus enim, et hendrerit arcu. Aliquam rutrum suscipit magna, sit amet dictum lectus molestie non\footnoteB{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}.

\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\autopar

Ut\footnoteC{Quisque varius.} a interdum elit\footnoteD{Ut ut risus varius.}. Donec consequat luctus leo, vitae ornare purus maximus id. Fusce iaculis lorem at lacus tristique tempus. Aliquam mattis sit amet elit non sagittis. Integer varius vehicula efficitur. Nullam euismod aliquet est, id suscipit risus blandit eget. Integer eleifend lacus eget nisi consectetur, blandit sollicitudin neque sollicitudin.

Phasellus diam risus, ullamcorper sit amet metus nec, fermentum pharetra est. Fusce eu magna eget nulla lobortis porttitor. Donec rhoncus justo quis sapien pharetra, vitae ornare est euismod. Duis venenatis libero a feugiat ultrices. In nec posuere diam. Cras ac velit eget dolor tempor gravida. Etiam ultricies gravida nunc vel consequat. Aenean nec neque nulla. Ut a interdum elit. Donec consequat luctus leo, vitae ornare purus maximus id. Fusce iaculis lorem at lacus tristique tempus. Aliquam mattis sit amet elit non sagittis. Integer varius vehicula efficitur. Nullam euismod aliquet est, id suscipit risus blandit eget. Integer eleifend lacus eget nisi consectetur, blandit sollicitudin neque sollicitudin. Suspendisse feugiat nisl sit amet tellus ullamcorper maximus. Donec enim neque, posuere in lorem at, laoreet fermentum lectus. Donec vel nisl aliquam, congue velit sagittis, finibus diam. In id ligula eleifend, facilisis libero ac, congue nunc. Nulla facilisis dui ut dolor posuere, venenatis varius felis tincidunt. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum eget euismod leo, pharetra feugiat odio. Maecenas maximus blandit pharetra. Donec eget risus nec justo mattis aliquam. Suspendisse erat dui, interdum ac posuere vitae, volutpat id justo. Phasellus accumsan dignissim convallis. Pellentesque fringilla facilisis nibh ut pellentesque. Pellentesque pretium libero vel elit dictum scelerisque. Aenean eu viverra magna, vel tristique dui. Fusce eleifend ante sit amet arcu congue, sed hendrerit dolor malesuada. Phasellus tincidunt velit id eros volutpat fringilla. Fusce a commodo elit. Morbi varius, sapien elementum ultrices sodales, turpis magna egestas quam, eget elementum nisl metus in eros. Sed placerat elit porta, venenatis magna ac, accumsan metus. Curabitur eget semper velit. Curabitur quis augue congue, semper purus ac, bibendum risus. Mauris lectus urna, commodo et placerat at, iaculis vitae velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque aliquam orci vitae lobortis pretium. Curabitur non mattis orci, non mattis purus. Proin nec ante sed lorem dictum blandit. Maecenas vel augue sagittis, faucibus quam id, lacinia nisl. Praesent accumsan odio a elit dignissim auctor. Cras eget metus ut urna molestie tristique. Donec varius rhoncus ultricies. Donec imperdiet, metus a accumsan molestie, neque metus luctus tellus, a scelerisque metus tortor finibus nunc. Nulla et ex at orci iaculis interdum. Proin in convallis ex. Aenean finibus dui vel enim posuere, sit amet mattis arcu hendrerit. Ut commodo mauris sed augue ultricies, sed consequat diam dapibus. Donec vestibulum mi quis lobortis fringilla\footnoteD{Donec non suscipit metus}.

\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: as maintener of reledmac, I can tell you : it is actually not possible, except with modification on the reledmac code. However, I have no time to do it while I have not written my phd thesis, so before summer or later. I suggest you to open an issue on the github page of reledmac.

Comment: @Maïeul: Thanks for your quick reply. That's nevertheless unfortunate. It might be a nice feature to have (in the future). By the way, thanks for managing to add the `\Xonlyside` & `\onlysideX` macros to `reledpar`; they're great features to have!

Comment: it will be included only if you open an issue ;-)

Comment: @Maïeul: Thanks for reminding me! I'll open an issue on the github page.